# Export files without background to websites

Tags: modeling, export, transparency, lighting

I'm trying to export a file I designed as a transparent glass with the correct lighting.

But there is a difference between exporting with a dark background and exporting a transparent background.

The problem:
The element without a background pops up with colors in the mountains and does not emphasize the lighting on the glass.

Comment: Hi, could you please add some images?